# I can not make friends Thymeleaf and Spring

Tags: spring, post, thymeleaf

when you click the search button an error occurs
in my html:

`<form method="post">
     <input type="number" name="numberProt">
     <button type="submit">Найти</button>
 </form>`

in my @Controller

```
@Controller
public class ViolationController {
    @Autowired
    private ViolationServiceImpl violationService;

    @GetMapping("/violations")
    public String viewViolations(Model model) {
        List<Violation> listViolations = violationService.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("listViolations", listViolations);

        return "violations";
    }

    @PostMapping("filterProt")
    public String filterViolation(Integer numberProt, Model model) {
        Iterable<Violation> protocols;
        if (numberProt != null) {
            protocols = violationService.findByNumProtocol(numberProt);
        } else {
            protocols = violationService.findAll();
        }
        model.addAttribute(protocols);
        return "/violations";
    }
}
```

I ask you to help. An error occurs:
Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]

Comment: Nothing is mapping your request parameter. And you are posting to which url? Should be `/filterProt` as that is what you added as URL in your `@PostMapping`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form is not correct, it has no action. Simply correct your form to this:

```
<form action="/filterProt" method="post">
   <input type="number" name="numberProt">
   <button type="submit">Найти</button>
</form>
```

Additionally, your controller handler lacks @ModelAttribute annotation:

```
@PostMapping("filterProt")
public String filterViolation(@ModelAttribute NumberModel numberModel, Model model) {
....
}
```

Where NumberModel is:

```
public class NumberModel{
    private Integer numberProt;

    public Integer getNumberProt() {
        return numberProt;
    }

    public void setNumberProt(Integer numberProt) {
        return this.numberProt = numberProt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help you =)